# How to capitalize words with brackets in sentence

Tags: php

I am using the following code to capitalize each word in a sentence, but I am unable to capitalize words with brackets attached.

PHP Code:

```
  <?php
     $str = "[this is the {command line (interface ";
     $output  = ucwords(strtolower($str));
     echo $output;
```

**Output:**

`[this Is The {command Line (interface`

**But my expected output should be:**

`[This Is The {Command Line (Interface`

How can I handle words with brackets?
There may be multiple brackets.

**For example:**

`[{this is the ({command line ({(interface`

I want to find a general solution/function in PHP.

Comment: View this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: `mb_convert_case('[this is the {command line (interface ', MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');` works just fine with those extra symbols in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$output = ucwords($str, ' [{(');
echo $output;
// output ->
// [This Is The {Command Line (Interface
```

---

**Update:** general solution. Here a "bracket" - is any non-letter character. Any letter, following the "bracket" is converted to uppercase.

```
$string = "test is the {COMMAND line -STRET (interface 5more 9words #here";
$strlowercase = strtolower($string);

$result = preg_replace_callback('~(^|[^a-zA-Z])([a-z])~', function($matches)
{
    return $matches[1] . ucfirst($matches[2]);
}, $strlowercase);


var_dump($result);
// string(62) "Test Is The {Command Line -Stret (Interface 5More 9Words #Here"
```

Live [demo](https://ideone.com/jCRRMQ)

Comment: probably don't want the `strtolower`.  What happens to `CLI` or `PHP`?

Comment: Other one I want to contain number with start word how to do it.
example 
3s [this is command line {interface
in this case 's' should be capital.

Comment: I have added $output = ucwords($str, ' [{(123456789'); 
but i have more brackets above 15.. Have proper solution that handle all brackets without define.because user can add any bracket that's not define in my code.

Comment: @Joe Black
But this "-STRET" letter is not converting into "-Stret" .
Please see this.
first i need all letter in lower case then first letter in uppercase.

Comment: @RaheelAslam Added `strtolower()`. Check it, please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145937/discussion-between-joe-black-and-raheel-aslam).

Comment: @Joe Black 
please check this example and verify not working after testing
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d28f30fe13ce69b0cc421aea1d4d6ad5fbe9938

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution, you can add more delimiters in the for-each loop array if you want to handle more characters.

```
function ucname($string) {
    $string =ucwords(strtolower($string));

    foreach (array('-', '\'') as $delimiter) {
      if (strpos($string, $delimiter)!==false) {
        $string =implode($delimiter, array_map('ucfirst', explode($delimiter, $string)));
      }
    }
    return $string;
}
?>
<?php
//TEST

$names =array(
  'JEAN-LUC PICARD',
  'MILES O\'BRIEN',
  'WILLIAM RIKER',
  'geordi la forge',
  'bEvErly CRuSHeR'
);
foreach ($names as $name) { print ucname("{$name}\n<br />"); }

//PRINTS:
/*
Jean-Luc Picard
Miles O'Brien
William Riker
Geordi La Forge
Beverly Crusher
*/
```